# Turning point where A>B becomes B>A

Tags: graphing-functions

For the relationship

$$A^2=246*B^5=C$$

When $ C>1$, $$A>B$$ for certain values of C such as $0.25$

$$ A>B$$

$$ A^2=246*B^5=0.25\,$$
$$ A=\sqrt{0.25}=0.5\,$$
$$ B=(0.25/256)^{1/5}=0.25$$

$$\ ∴A>B\,$$

But when C gets closer to $0$ e.g. $3\cdot 10^{-3}$
$$ B>A$$

$$ A^2=246*B^5=3\cdot 10^{-3},$$
$$ A=\sqrt{3\cdot 10^{-3}}=0.05$$
$$ B=(3\cdot 10^{-3}/256)^{1/5}=0.1$$

$$\ ∴B>A\,$$

**1.Where is (or how do I find) the turning point between when $A>B$ to $B>A$?**

I know it is somewhere at a positive near $0$ value.

**2.Why does this occur at such an unusual place? E.g. if $A>B$ for all values over $0$ and  $B>A$ for all values <$0$ this would make some sense, but what does it occur at a value between $3E-3$ and $0.25$.**

[image]

If you are after some context, I ran into the problem when working on a question I asked on Chemistry Stack Exchange [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62646/if-pq-t2u2-rs2-and-vw4-have-the-same-ksp-which-has-the-lowest-solubility-in-m) but it is a bit out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turning point is when $A=B$, that is $A^2=246A^5$ or $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{246}}$. Then $$C=A^2=\frac{1}{246^{2/3}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{246}}{246}.$$